# Garbage collection seems to be quite flaky in .NET 6.0

Tags: garbage-collection, .net-6.0

I have a TCP connections server written in .NET 6.0. Clients establish TCP connections with the server using SslStream, send and receive data, then disconnect.

While hundreds of connections are being established, data sent and received, then disconnected repeatedly, I observed the server's memory usage to keep going up, from around **120 MB** to **900 MB** in the cause of a few hours, then drop back to around **120 MB**. This cycle kept repeating.

To find out what is causing the huge memory increase, I used "dotnet-gcdump" to take a memory dump. But as soon as the dump is taken, the memory drops back to 120 MB. So it is clear to me that the action of taking a memory dump triggered the garbage collection.

So I can't even figure out what code of mine is causing this memory increase because the action of taking the dump triggers the garbage collection therefore the dump always shows minimal memory usage.

So I added a timer-triggered call on **GC.Collect()** every minute. The huge memory increase no longer happens.

All the above observations seem to indicate that the garbage collection in .NET 6.0 doesn't trigger until it accumulates 800 MB of garbage. This is really bad because 800 MB of wasted memory is really bad. Why is it happening? Is .NET buggy?